# Why the following Java makeBricks solution fails?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to correct the solution for the following codingbat question? Thanks in advance.

I am getting `OK` for all the test cases except for the unknown `"Other Tests"`.

**Specification:**

We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return true if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks.

**Code Snippet:**

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if (goal == 0) return true;

  if (goal < big * 5) {
    goal = goal - small; //Use all the small bricks each of inch 1
    while (goal > 0) {
      goal = goal - 5;
      --big;
      if (big == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return (goal == 0);
  }
  else {
    goal = goal - (big * 5); //Use all the big bricks each of inch 5
    while (goal > 0) {
      goal = goal - 1;
      --small;
      if (small == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return (goal == 0);
  }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

After working hard I found the solution which works for all the test cases. It is

```
  return ((goal <= small + big * 5) && goal % 5 <= small);
```

But, just for the sake of curiosity I want to know why the above code snippet doesn't work for every case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if goal is 0? As in: makeBricks(5, 10, 0)?

Comment: The answer is the same. No change. I included if (goal == 0) return 0 case also.

Comment: @csmckelvey Found the solution after working hard a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @csmckelvey return ((goal <= small + big * 5) && goal % 5 <= small); 
is the solution. It passes all the tests.

Comment: Good to know you got a solution. I will look into it a bit more today and see if I can get you an explanation like you ask for in your edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails whenever `big * 5 > goal` and `small % 5 != 0` such as in this case:

```
makeBricks(1, 2, 5)
```

It should return `true` but returns `false` instead.  The first two lines of your code make it impossible to meet this case:

```
if (goal < big * 5) {
    goal = goal - small; //Use all the small bricks each of inch 1
```

Once you subtract `small` from `goal`, you can never meet the goal with `big` bricks (unless small is a multiple of 5).

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
if(small > goal)
   return true;
   if(goal - (big*5) <= small && goal - (big*5) >= 0 )
      return true;
else if(big* 5 > goal){
   if( goal/5 < big && goal%5 <= small)
     return true;
 }
return false;
}
```

I had the same problem as you with the same lines but then changed my code to this and it works